# CakePHP: Add css to the entire Controller?

Tags: cakephp

There is anyway to add a specific css to the entire controller?

If I want to add to a view I simply add:

```
<?php echo $this->css('css_name'); ?>
```

But how to add this css to the entire controller?

Edit:
I know I can add the css to the layout, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if its possible to give a controller a css.

What i know and use is to give a controller an othor layout like this:

```
$this->layout = 'name of the layout';
```

With this you can give it an other Css..
Use it inside a `function` or for the whole controller in de `beforeFilter()`

Answer (score 0):

Put inside you code in default.ctp

Path : app/View/Layouts/default.ctp

```
echo $this->Html->css('css_name');
```